# I made an AppleScript app and Siri won't launch it

Tags: macos, applescript, applications, spotlight, siri

I followed iFixit [tutorial](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Create+a+Shortcut+Application+for+pairing+your+AirPods/112798) how to make "AirPods connect" app for Mac. It works perfectly but I cannot run it with Siri. Using Spotlight or clicking on it works, but Siri won't open it and says "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that." What am I missing? Other apps open with Siri just fine.

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "SystemUIServer"
    -- Working CONNECT Script.  Goes through the following:
    -- Clicks on Bluetooth Menu (OSX Top Menu Bar)
    --    => Clicks on SX-991 Item
    --      => Clicks on Connect Item
    set btMenu to (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "bluetooth")
    tell btMenu
      click
      tell (menu item "SX-991" of menu 1)
        click
        if exists menu item "Connect" of menu 1 then
          click menu item "Connect" of menu 1
          return "Connecting..."
        else
          click btMenu -- Close main BT drop down if Connect wasn't present
          return "Connect menu was not found, are you already connected?"
        end if
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure that the AppleScript file is a .app (Application) not a .scpt (AppleScript). To do this, create a new file in Script Editor, copy and paste your code, and save as an Application. Once it is a .app file, put it in the Applications folder. Siri should be able to do it then.

Comment: The OP states he followed the tutorial which shows saving as an application and even giving the application permission under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility > Privacy. He also states it works from Spotlight and or clicking it. So it is definitely not a .scpt file and is a .app file!

Comment: Is it in the applications folder? It should work then. macOS only recogonizes apps in the /System/Applications or /Applications directory as Apps even if it is a .app file.

Comment: RE: "macOS only recogonizes apps in the /System/Applications or /Applications directory as Apps even if it is a .app file." -- That is not at all true as I have many applications that I've created that are not in those locations and Siri has no problem opening them!

Comment: What version of macOS are you on? macOS Catalina requires it to be in the /Applications or /System/Applications directory from my experience.

Answer (score -1):

Try dragging it to the applications folder. Siri may only be able to open apps that are in the applications folder. Or you might be able to use Automator.

Comment: It was already mentioned in the other answer to put it in the Applications folder, however this is not necessary or a requirement, as I mentioned in a comment to the other answer "_ ... That is not at all true as I have many applications that I've created that are not in those locations and Siri has no problem opening them!_" and to add to that... I've tested this in many differ versions of **macOS** including **macOS Catalina** and **Siri** opens my **AppleScript** apps wherever I've placed them!